# Equality of $2$nd compound matrices implies equality up to sign

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, multilinear-algebra

There’s a bit of multilinear-algebraic folklore knocking around in my head that I’d like to cite and use but that I can’t track down for the life of me:

> Let $n > 2$ be an integer, and let $a,b \in \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. If $\bigwedge^2 a = \bigwedge^2 b$, then $a=\pm b$.

Note that the condition $\bigwedge^2 a = \bigwedge^2 b$ is equivalent to the equality $C_2(a) = C_2(b)$ of $2$nd compound matrices, but I’ve had no luck so far with what seem to be the usual references for compound matrix lore. So, assuming that this half-remembered lore is correctly remembered, is there a handy citation one can provide for it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If $a$ and $b$ are both rank one, then $C_2(a)$ and $C_2(b)$ are both zero, but $a$ and $b$ are not the same up to a sign...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm only interested in the case of invertible matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C_2$ is a multiplicative operator, we have
$$C_2(A) = C_2(B) \Longrightarrow C_2(A B^{-1}) = C_2(B B^{-1}) = I.$$
So it suffices to show that for an $n \times n$ matrix $M$, $C_2(M) = I$ iff $M = \pm I$. This can be seen as follows: we have
$$M_{11} M_{22} - M_{12} M_{21} = 1, M_{11} M_{23} = M_{21}M_{13}, M_{12} M_{23} = M_{22}M_{13}.$$
So if $(M_{13}, M_{23})$ is not the zero vector, then $(M_{11}, M_{21})$ and $(M_{12}, M_{22})$ are both its scalar multiplication, meaning that $M_{11} M_{22} - M_{12} M_{21} = 0$, contradiction! So we have $M_{13} = M_{23} = 0$.

Symmetrically, one can show that all off-diagonal elements are zero. Finally, note that $M_{ii} M_{jj} = 1$ for any $i \neq j$, so it follows that the diagonal elements are either all $1$ or all $-1$.

Comment: I feel like a doofus for not checking by hand when $C_2(I) = I$. Thank you.